# Is it possible to share data between multiple classes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I was wondering whether it is possible to change the data in one instance of a class, so that it'll cause the change of the data in the second class in the OOP approach?

What I mean is

```
class Data {
    constructor() { this.data = 5 }
}

class First extends Data {
    constructor() { super() }
    changeData(_data) { this.data = _data }
}

class Second extends Data {
    constructor() { super() }
    changeData(_data) { this.data = _data }
}


const first = new First()
const second = new Second()

first.changeData(7)
console.log(first.data)
console.log(second.data) // I want 7 here as well
```

Or just any solution of sharing data between classes in the OOP?

Comment: you'll have to pass the same reference to both

Comment: How would you like to link `first` and `second`? Seems like it’d have to be done somehow, or what happens when you create another pair of `new First()` and `new Second()`? (Maybe you could explain the real-world problem behind this, too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to solve this by adding the ability to manually specify the object to use for storage of its members.

In this example `first` and `second` have linked storage and `third` and `fourth` have linked storage, different from that used for `first` and `second`.

```js
class Data {
  constructor(storage) {
    this.storage = storage;
    this.storage.data = 5
  }
}

class First extends Data {
  constructor(storage) { super(storage) }
  changeData(_data) { this.storage.data = _data }
}

class Second extends Data {
  constructor(storage) { super(storage) }
  changeData(_data) { this.storage.data = _data }
}


storage = {};
const first = new First(storage)
const second = new Second(storage)

storageB = {};
const third = new First(storageB)
const fourth = new Second(storageB)

first.changeData(7)
third.changeData(21)

console.log(first.storage.data) // 7
console.log(second.storage.data) // 7
console.log(third.storage.data) // 21
console.log(fourth.storage.data) // 21
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE
I think I've found a solution to the problem

```
const data = {
    name: 'John'
}

class First {
    constructor(data) { this.data = data }
    changeData() { this.data.age = 12 }
}

class Second {
    constructor(data) { this.data = data }
}


const first = new First(data)
const second = new Second(data)

console.log(first.data)
console.log(second.data)

first.changeData()

console.log(first.data)
console.log(second.data)
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using classes check out the static flag(sharing memory across the instances), if you are functional just trace the scope